# Синхронизация приложения при изменении базы данных

Tags: android, sqlite

Делаю приложение Учительский журнал, необходимо чтобы учитель на своем телефоне выставлял оценку и студенты смогли посмотреть сразу изменения.
Как можно выполнить синхронизацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классический вариант. Пишете серверную часть, например на PHP с использованием MySQL. А, приложение на телефоне пусть обменивается с ней данными при помощи REST API и PUSH уведомлений.  Как-то так...

Comment: Не могу найти в интернете примеры реализации

Comment: Здесь уже ничем не могу помочь. А, вообще подобные вещи пишутся самостоятельно. Своими руками.

Comment: существуют бесплатные хостинги где можно разместить серверную часть?

Comment: @Владимир можно даже без PHP обойтись - достаточно будет просто общую базу держать, а приложение пусть к базе подключается. Можно даже сделать вариант синхронизации базы приложения с базой сервера, а при запуске сверять к примеру контрольную сумму БД на сервере с последней сохраненной в приложении... Вариантов море - действуйте.

Comment: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) отлично справится с этим. Не нужно ни хостинг покупать, ни писать сервер. И синхронизация из коробки.

Answer (score 0):

Почему для такой простой задачи не попробовать простой подход: в облачном БЕСПЛАТНОМ сервисе хранить SQLite файл, который доступен для чтения всем студентам, а для записи одному преподавателю? Этот подход реально реализуем для Владимира, потому как требует написания приложения ТОЛЬКО на андроиде и на порядок (в 10 раз) дешевле, чем написание серверного приложения, организации своего хостинга и домена, поддерживающего MySQL, прописывание процедуры авторизации и т.д. И он в бесконечно раз дешевле по материальным затратам.